# Is there any way to stop execution on dialog open?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to stop execution, like when confirmed dialogue open on Ui dialogue and resume when OK clicked.

```
dilog.dialog('open');
```

Comment: This is not possible. You need to move the code after `dilog.dialog('open');` in a separate function that you call when the dialog is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting the user to make a confirmation you'll need a UI confirmation modal

Here are the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation), usage is:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:140,
    modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Delete all items": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
    Cancel: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
    }
    });
});
```